# REGEX to find an option tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Basically, I am generating a drop-down (select) list which uses data which I retrieve from my database.

I then store the id and name in the `gSections` array.

I need to loop through the array I have and see if there is an option tag already in a variable which I have set.

Here is my code:

```
    for( s in gSections ){
        if( THE FIND WAS NOT FOUND  ){
            resources += '<option name="' + gSections[s].id + '">' + gSections[s].name + '</option>';
        }
    }

$('select[name="resources"]').html( resources );
```

The HTML before having the options inserted is:

```
    <select name="resource">
        <option value="select" selected="true">Please select...</option>
    </select>
```

The gSections array is as so (from console.log()):

```
[Object { id="1471", name="test1"}, Object { id="1470", name="Test2"}, Object { id="1471", name="test1"}]
```

So in the end, I only want one of each element which is in the array to be in my drop down list.

If you can think of any better ways of doing it please feel free to suggest.

I know this may sound messed up or whatever but I'm not very good at explaining things, so feel free to ask questions.

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript is a language **prefect** for manipulating the DOM, Y U NO USE THAT?!?!?!. Just kidding, use DOM manipulation instead of inserting it as a string, it's a better approach and much better handled by the browser and your code.

Comment: Do not use regexes for HTML tags!

Comment: @Truth I am using the jQuery .html (.innerHTML) to "manipulate" the DOM. How else would I do it?

Comment: Please show a sample of the HTML you're parsing, otherwise suggesting better methods or determining a proper RegExp are near impossible.

Comment: I have added the bit of HTML that is being edited

Comment: Are you retrieving HTML from your DB or just string that might need to become options? Please show an example of a gSection array

Comment: You appear to be using jQuery. Retagged the question for you.

Comment: Okay thanks @pete; And I have added the gSections array (part of it) to the original post now

Comment: @DarkMantis What I mean is you should create **nodes** rather than using HTML strings.

Comment: @Truth I have done exactly that now, and if you want to craete an answer for it, I'll happily except it.

Comment: @DarkMantis: Posted with a working example. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use strings to append HTML to the DOM with JavaScript, JavaScript's a bit more sophisticated than that.

You can create `<option>` elements as Nodes and append them to the `<select>` element.

**[Here's a live example of what I mean](http://jsbin.com/iwizur/edit#preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Combine all sections with the same id into one object, then iterate:

```
var gSectionIds = {};
for (var i = 0; i < gSections.length; i++) {
    gSectionIds[gSections[i].id] = gSections[i];
}
for (var s in gSectionIds) {
    resources += '<option name="' + gSectionIds[s].id + '">' + 
                 gSectionIds[s].name + '</option>';
}
```

### [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/nApMm/)